# Corona test project Works at emulator but not on the Device

Tags: lua, coronasdk, emulation, device, scene

I have this weird situation. I have 2 scenes. I can go from 1 to the other in the simulator but it crashes when I do the same on the device...

This is the code of the first scene (menu)

### menu.lua

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

-- include Corona s "widget" library 
local widget = require ("widget")

-- forward declarations and other locals
local playBtn
local optsBtn
local helpBtn



-- Levels Menu
local function onPlayBtnRelease()
    -- ads.hide()
    storyboard.gotoScene( "levels", "fade", 500 )
    return true -- indicates successful touch
end

-- Options
local function onOptionsBtnRelease()
    storyboard.gotoScene( "options", "fade", 500 )
    return true -- indicates successful touch
end

-- Help
local function onHelpBtnRelease()
    storyboard.gotoScene( "help", "fade", 500 )
    return true -- indicates successful touch
end


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- BEGINNING OF YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
-- 
-- NOTE: Code outside of listener functions (below) will only be executed once,
--       unless storyboard.removeScene() is called.
-- 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Called when the scene s view does not exist:
function scene:createScene( event )
    local group = self.view
    
    -- display a background image
    local background = display.newImageRect( "background.jpg", display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight )
    background:setReferencePoint( display.TopLeftReferencePoint )
    background.x, background.y = 0, 0

    -- create/position logo/title image on upper-half of the screen
    local titleLogo = display.newImageRect( "title.png", 264, 42 )
    titleLogo:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
    titleLogo.x = display.contentWidth * 0.5
    titleLogo.y = display.contentHeight / 5

    -- create a widget button (which will loads levels.lua on release)
    playBtn = widget.newButton{
        label="Play Now",
        labelColor = { default={255}, over={128} },
        defaultFile="button.png",
        overFile="button-over.png",
        width=154, height=40,
        onRelease = onPlayBtnRelease    -- event listener function
    }
    playBtn:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
    playBtn.x = display.contentWidth*0.5
    playBtn.y = display.contentHeight * 2 / 5

    -- button for options (options.lua)
    optsBtn = widget.newButton{
        label="Options",
        labelColor = { default={255}, over={128} },
        defaultFile="button.png",
        overFile="button-over.png",
        width=154, height=40,
        onRelease = onOptionsBtnRelease -- event listener function
    }
    optsBtn:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
    optsBtn.x = display.contentWidth*0.5
    optsBtn.y = display.contentHeight * 3 / 5

    -- button for options (help.lua)
    helpBtn = widget.newButton{
        label="Help",
        labelColor = { default={255}, over={128} },
        defaultFile="button.png",
        overFile="button-over.png",
        width=154, height=40,
        onRelease = onHelpBtnRelease    -- event listener function
    }
    helpBtn:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
    helpBtn.x = display.contentWidth*0.5
    helpBtn.y = display.contentHeight * 4 / 5
    
    -- Load Configurations
    local utili = require( "utility" )
    mySettings = utili.loadTable("BlastsOptions.json")
    
    -- all display objects must be inserted into group
    group:insert( background )
    group:insert( titleLogo )
    group:insert( playBtn )
    group:insert( optsBtn )
    group:insert( helpBtn )
end

-- Called immediately after scene has moved onscreen:
function scene:enterScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    -- INSERT code here (e.g. start timers, load audio, start listeners, etc.)
    -- Audio ***
    
    
    local menusound = audio.loadStream("sounds/menusback.mp3")
    if mySettings.musicOn == true then
        audio.play (menusound, {loop=-1})
    end
    
    
    
end

-- Called when scene is about to move offscreen:
function scene:exitScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    -- INSERT code here (e.g. stop timers, remove listenets, unload sounds, etc.)
    audio.stop()
end

-- If scene s view is removed, scene:destroyScene() will be called just prior to:
function scene:destroyScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    --if playBtn then
    --    playBtn:removeSelf()    -- widgets must be manually removed
    --    playBtn = nil
    --end
    
end

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- END OF YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- "createScene" event is dispatched if scene s view does not exist
scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )

-- "enterScene" event is dispatched whenever scene transition has finished
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )

-- "exitScene" event is dispatched whenever before next scene s transition begins
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )

-- "destroyScene" event is dispatched before view is unloaded, which can be
-- automatically unloaded in low memory situations, or explicitly via a call to
-- storyboard.purgeScene() or storyboard.removeScene().
scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

And this is the code of the second one:

Can you help me to find what could be wrong?

### levels.lua

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()
-- include Corona s "widget" library 
local widget = require ("widget")
--------------------------------------------

local function onKeyEvent( event )
    if (event.keyName == "back") and (system.getInfo("platformName") == "Android") then
        storyboard.gotoScene( "menu", "fade", 500 )
        return true
    end
    return false
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "key", onKeyEvent );



-- forward declarations and other locals
local play1Btn
local play2Btn
local menuBtn

-- 'onRelease' event listener for playBtn
local function onLeve1BtnRelease()
    -- go to level1.lua scene
    
    audio.stop ()
    storyboard.gotoScene( "level1", "fade", 500 )
    return true -- indicates successful touch
end

local function onLeve2BtnRelease()
    -- go to level1.lua scene
    -- ads.hide()
    storyboard.gotoScene( "level1", "fade", 500 )
    return true -- indicates successful touch
end

local function onMenuBtnRelease()
    -- go to level1.lua scene
    storyboard.gotoScene( "menu", "fade", 500 )
    return true -- indicates successful touch
end

-- Called when the scene s view does not exist:
function scene:createScene( event )
    local group = self.view
    -- display a background image
    local background = display.newImageRect( "background.jpg", display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight )
    background:setReferencePoint( display.TopLeftReferencePoint )
    background.x, background.y = 0, 0
    
    -- create/position logo/title image on upper-half of the screen
    local titleLogo = display.newImageRect( "select-Level.png", 264, 42 )
    titleLogo:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
    titleLogo.x = display.contentWidth * 0.5
    titleLogo.y = display.contentHeight / 5
    
    -- create a widget button (which will loads level1.lua on release)
    play1Btn = widget.newButton{
        label="Level 1",
        labelColor = { default={255}, over={128} },
        defaultFile="button.png",
        overFile="button-over.png",
        width=154, height=40,
        onRelease = onLeve1BtnRelease    -- event listener function
    }
    play1Btn:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
    play1Btn.x = display.contentWidth*0.5
    play1Btn.y = display.contentHeight * 2 / 5
    
    -- button for options (options.lua)
    play2Btn = widget.newButton{
        label="Level 2",
        labelColor = { default={255}, over={128} },
        defaultFile="button.png",
        overFile="button-over.png",
        width=154, height=40,
        onRelease = onLeve2BtnRelease -- event listener function
    }
    play2Btn:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
    play2Btn.x = display.contentWidth*0.5
    play2Btn.y = display.contentHeight * 3 / 5

    -- button for options (help.lua)
    menuBtn = widget.newButton{
        label="Return",
        labelColor = { default={255}, over={128} },
        defaultFile="button.png",
        overFile="button-over.png",
        width=154, height=40,
        onRelease = onMenuBtnRelease    -- event listener function
    }
    menuBtn:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
    menuBtn.x = display.contentWidth*0.5
    menuBtn.y = display.contentHeight * 4 / 5

    -- all display objects must be inserted into group
    group:insert( background )
    group:insert( titleLogo )
    group:insert( play1Btn )
    group:insert( play2Btn )
    group:insert( menuBtn )
end

-- Called immediately after scene has moved onscreen:
function scene:enterScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    -- INSERT code here (e.g. start timers, load audio, start listeners, etc.)

end

-- Called when scene is about to move offscreen:
function scene:exitScene( event )
    local group = self.view

end

-- If scene s view is removed, scene:destroyScene() will be called just prior to:
function scene:destroyScene( event )
    local group = self.view


end

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- END OF YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- "createScene" event is dispatched if scene s view does not exist
scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )

-- "enterScene" event is dispatched whenever scene transition has finished
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )

-- "exitScene" event is dispatched whenever before next scene s transition begins
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )

-- "destroyScene" event is dispatched before view is unloaded, which can be
-- automatically unloaded in low memory situations, or explicitly via a call to
-- storyboard.purgeScene() or storyboard.removeScene().
scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

Very very Thanks. I'm new on Corona and I'm stuck on this :(

Comment: Make sure that the naming and capitalization of images and other resources are correct...

Comment: What device are you running the application on? You can always look at the console while running using Xcode (iOS) or Android Debug Bridge to see if you get any error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

krs is correct!

I have disrespected the resource naming convention.

I put "-" in the name of the images files and it is not allowed.

Problem was solved changing the name of the images.